# Break even analysis using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, I have sales data regarding a particular product. I want to figure out when I am going to break even. I.E., given the sales figures for each month, during which month did the total exceed a given break-even point?

```
Total Sales $ Required to Break Even:    $2,918,607

             Jan-00   Feb-00   Mar-00   Apr-00   May-00   Jun-00   Jul-00
Sales $     351,000  386,100  424,710  467,181  513,899  614,250  614,250
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for your example to be understood, and the units don't appear to be consistent.  Provide the formulas you want to use for the calculations.  Once you explain your problem, also describe what you have researched and tried.  People will help you solve a specific problem you can't solve yourself, but the site is not a free coding service.

Comment: Are the sales values cumulative or are they per-month?

Comment: @EngineerToast: brilliant edit, and nice job on the answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use helper rows above the month names that calculates running total of sales (in units or dollars - one row for each), compares it to the break-even figure you have already determined and flags if it surpasses that. Then you just need to use a HLOOKUP to find that cell and return the month name from below it.

If you expand on your question a bit, I might be able to expand on my answer more...

---

**Example:**

[image: Example]

CSV Version: (Dates shown as numeric values)

```
,36526,36557,36586,36617,36647,36678,36708
Sales,351000,386100,424710,467181,513899,614250,614250
Total Sales,351000,737100,1161810,1628991,2142890,2757140,3371390
Break Even?,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
```

The formula for `B3` is `=SUM($B$2:B$2)` and dragged to the right. Notice that the first reference (`$B$2`) is absolute and the second one (`B$2`) is relative for the column so it updates as you drag it to the right. The formula in `H3` will be `=SUM($B$2:H$2)`.

The formula for `B4` is `=AND(B3>2918607,A3<2918607)` and is dragged to the right. Note that I hard-coded the target value but you could easily change it to reference some cell instead.

Now you have to different ways to find the first month that exceeds the break-even point.

Method 1: Find the first `Total Sales` value that exceeds the target and pull the month above it using the formula `=TEXT(OFFSET($B$1,0,MATCH(2918607,B3:H3)),"mmm-yy")`.

Method 2: Find the first - and should be only - `TRUE` value for `Break Even?` and return the month above it using the formula `=TEXT(OFFSET($B$1,0,MATCH(TRUE,B4:H4)),"mmm-yy")`.

Comment: Thanks for the huge expansion and detail, Engineer Toast! You should probably have just added that as an answer so we could vote it up (I would not have minded at all).